# Safe Multi-thread access in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-forms-designer

I am trying to implement a chat. I have taken a code [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BDVfpPq3weo)

When I send messages I have an error:

> Control 'ListMessage' name accessed from a thread other than the
>   thread it was created on.

where ListMessage is a ListView added with Visual Studio.

```
       private void buttonSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //convert string message to byte[]
            ASCIIEncoding aEncoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] sendingMessage = new byte[1500];
            sendingMessage = aEncoding.GetBytes(textMessage.Text);
            //sending the encoded message
            sck.Send(sendingMessage);
            //adding to the list box
            listMessage.Items.Add("Me:" + textMessage.Text);
            textMessage.Text = "";
        }

        private void MessageCallBack(IAsyncResult aResult)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] receivedData = new byte[1500];
                receivedData = (byte[])aResult.AsyncState;
                //converting byte[] to string
                ASCIIEncoding aEncoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
                string receivedMessage = aEncoding.GetString(receivedData);

                //Adding this message into list box
///// error is given in the following line/////
                listMessage.Items.Add("Friend:" + receivedMessage);

                buffer = new byte[1500];
                sck.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref epRemote, new AsyncCallback(MessageCallBack), buffer);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

I have tried to use Invoke as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-make-thread-safe-calls-to-windows-forms-controls) but I have errors

```
        private void MessageCallBack(IAsyncResult aResult)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] receivedData = new byte[1500];
                receivedData = (byte[])aResult.AsyncState;
                //converting byte[] to string
                ASCIIEncoding aEncoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
                string receivedMessage = aEncoding.GetString(receivedData);

                //Adding this message into list box
                //listMessage.Items.Add("Friend:" + receivedMessage);
                listMessage.AddItemSafe("Friend:" + receivedMessage);

                buffer = new byte[1500];
                sck.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref epRemote, new AsyncCallback(MessageCallBack), buffer);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void AddItemSafe(string text)
        {
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                AddItemSafeCallback a = new AddItemSafeCallback(AddItemSafe);
                this.Invoke(a, new object[] { text });
            }
            else
            {
                this.Items.Add(text);
            }
        }

        delegate void AddItemSafeCallback(string text);
```

Erros are:

- 'ListBox' does not contain a definition fo 'AddItemSafe' and no extension methode. 'AddItemSafe' accepting a first argument of type 'ListBox'could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference'
- 'MyUserControl' does not contain a definition fo 'AddItemSafe' and no extension methode. 'Item' accepting a first argument of type
  'ListBox'could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
  assembly reference'

My questions:

- Do you believe the way I try to fix to initial problem is the good
  one ?
- If yes, what is the problem with the solution I try to
  implement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the approach is quite correct, but you did miss a few things with the implementation.

The `AddItemSafe` method is just a method inside your form descendant class, not a method on `listMessage` (whatever type that may be). So when you call that, you only have to specify the method name and the parameter and not call it on an another object instance.

```
...
ASCIIEncoding aEncoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
string receivedMessage = aEncoding.GetString(receivedData);
//Adding this message into list box
//listMessage.Items.Add("Friend:" + receivedMessage);

// !!!!Note difference here:
AddItemSafe("Friend:" + receivedMessage);
...
```

Then, inside the AddItemSafe method, you do exactly what you would do in a single threaded environment, i.e. add to the items of `listMessage`. If invoke is required, then you wrap the whole thing into a delegate.

```
private void AddItemSafe(string text)
{
  if (this.InvokeRequired)
  {
    AddItemSafeCallback a = new AddItemSafeCallback(AddItemSafe);
    this.Invoke(a, new object[] { text });
  }
  else
  {
    // !!!!Note difference here:
    listmessage.Items.Add(text);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you it works !  I think I don't understand well how  'Invoke' and 'delegate' works : If AddItemSafe is not a method of ListMessage, how the invoke will "know" that ?

Comment: The Invoke does not have to know that. The Invoke simply calls the delegate on the same thread as the one that created the form and listMessage. The delegate in turn calls the AddItemSafe method and inside that method the parameter is added to listMessage. The delegate doesn't have to know about listMessage because AddItemSafe is the one that knows about it. The delegate is only there to make the cross-thread call of AddItemSafe via Invoke possible.

Comment: Ok, so when there are 2 different threads, this.InvokeRequired is true --> delegate is called and AddItemSafe is called again but this time this.InvokeRequired is false and we call 'listmessage.Items.Add(text);'. Is that correct ?

Comment: Yes, that is basically correct. InvokeRequired is true if you are on a thread other than the one that created the control. When it is called the first time, you are on the callback thread, so it is true, so the delegate is called via Invoke, which calls back to the owning thread, where InvokeRequired is now false.